# Strange Speedtest results

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection

I just got a fiber internet package which is advertised as max 20MBit down/ 1MBit up. However I'm getting some strange results on speedtest.net...

[image]

That doesn't look strange, but what happens **is the upload speed shows 8MBit up until the last couple of seconds of the test and then it jumps down suddenly to 1MBit**. Is this a bug in Speedtest? Or is my up speed more like 8MBit rather than 1?

Also just one hour ago, i was consistenly getting 40MBit down and only 512KBit up... not sure what to make of that? It's a FTTH connection and i'm connected via wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Check different speedtest site http://www.broadband.gov/qualitytest
Is it possible to test wired connection? Wireless may depend on your range

Comment: tested with wire... same results... the up speed goes up to around 8mb for most of the test until it shoots down to 1mb at the very end. Are they capping me? Once it shoots down to 1mb it wont go back above that level.

Comment: If you are paying for a rated speed at 1Mb/s for upload, then yes, they are probably capping it at that. Fiber can be configured for anything within the range that the trunk can handle, so yes, at some point in the circuit, they are limiting you to what you are paying for and that circuit is certainly capable of much much more. Chances are what you are seeing is some glitch in the way they limit the circuit.

Comment: hmm but they don't cap download? I'm getting over 20mb consistently whilst paying for 20mb.

Comment: Maybe your provider has a cap on upload and download is open. Clarify with provider

Comment: 20Mb/s is a capped download. Fiber can hit much higher than that. The 20 is already a limitation imposed on the circuit.